# Kendo tooltip loading-time placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to show some loading time content while waiting for ajax content?
At the moment my code shows empty square before its content loaded.
[image]

i would like to have something like this
[image]

my current code:

```
<span class="info-icon" id="roleTooltipIcon"></span>

@(Html.Kendo()
    .Tooltip()
    .For("#roleTooltipIcon")
    .LoadContentFrom(Url.Action("Tooltip", "TooltipController"))
    .ShowAfter(700)
    .Position(TooltipPosition.Left)
    .Width(600))
```

Comment: Try adding .Content("html for spinner in here"). My guess is that you will see that initially which will then be replaced when the ajax call returns. If it works, I can post this as an answer if you wish.

Comment: Also see here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/tooltip/ajax. That appears to automatically show a progress spinner whilst the content loads. Not sure why you are not seeing that. Possibly your version of kendo is an older version that doesn't have that?

Comment: looks like our version doesnt support it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was connected to kendo CSS where spinner content was defined.
It refered nonexisting gif.

Comment: Could you explain that in a little bit more detail so it can be helpful for others, too? Thanks!